# can I check out the code on windows machine?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Can I svn co "svn checkout" on my windows machine... without using svn tortoise? Is there any other method?

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't use tortoise? And yes, there is a command-line svn client for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can just install subversion. Windows binaries are located here: http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/ (http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can download command-line subversion clients for Windows from the [Subversion Project website](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows).

Answer (score 2):

Sure.
Donwload SVN package from here http://subversion.apache.org/
Then you can use svn from command line.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can install cygwin and a svn client with it. Seems like a lot more work though.

Comment: can you give details of svn client..I installed cygwin

Comment: @garima You have to select the subversion package from the cygwin installer. Have a look at this http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/howto/cygwin.html under install and config steps.

Answer (score -1):

Am I correct in saying you are looking for a terminal command for Windows? In that case you are out of luck. CMD in Windows will not cut it. Try installing Cygwin. It might help.

Comment: +1. I don't understand the drive-by dv. Installing Cygwin is a reasonable idea. Be sure to also install rxvt and escape the dos box completely.

Comment: there are native windows binaries.

Comment: Why exactly installing more than you need is a reasonable idea? Dos box? Unless you mean DosBox - there's no such thing. As far as console replacement go, it's a good idea. I use Console2.

Comment: @DigitalRoss @Mchl can you provide me details of DosBox.. or should I go with cygwin and svn client ?

Comment: @garima: DosBox has nothing to do with your issue. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSBox Just install native windows binaries like others say.

Comment: So, the idea we had was (1) you wanted a command line, as many of us do. (2) the windows CLI is crummy. (3) So kill two birds w/ one stone and install Cygwin. (4) With Cygwin installed, the final dotting-of-the-i's-and-crossing-of-t's is accomplished for some people by installing the Cygwin rxvt program, which is kind of like an xterm.

Comment: -1 @Daniel Johannes Louw: He's not out of luck.  There are command line packages available for Windows as well as other stand alone GUI clients as well add ons for most IDE's such as Visual Studio and Eclipse.